# Как обратиться к пропу родителя из прокидываемого в родитель элемента?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть два компонента

```
  function ComponentB(props) {
    return <div>{props.children}</div>;
  }

  function ComponentA() {
    const data = {
      title: "test",
      image: "http://mem/pep.png",
      users: [{ id: 1, name: "kek" }],
    };
    return (
      <ComponentB card={data}>
        // Как тут использовать пропы родителя?
        <header>{this.props.card.title}</header>
      </ComponentB>
    );
  }
```

ComponentB рендерит `children`, `ComponentA` рендерит `ComponentB` с передачей пропа `card`, вопрос состоит в том как использовать то что содержится в пропе внутри `children` элементов `ComponentB`, т.е. так чтобы header использовал пропсы родительского компонента.

Comment: Можете детализировать ваш пример и вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить доступ к пропам родительского компонента внутри children элементов, можно использовать специальную пропсу props.children и передавать ее дальше в качестве пропса. Также можно использовать деструктуризацию пропса внутри дочернего компонента для более удобного доступа к его свойствам.

```
function ComponentB(props) {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}

function ComponentA() {
  const data = {
    title: "test",
    image: "http://mem/pep.png",
    users: [{ id: 1, name: "kek" }],
  };
  return (
    <ComponentB card={data}>
      {({card}) => ( // Деструктуризация пропса внутри ComponentB
        <header>{card.title}</header>
      )}
    </ComponentB>
  );
}
```